How to embed a very simple drawing tool on my website
I would like to embed a very simple drawing tool on my website. It should cover a small area on the website. Only basic features like drawing with the mouse, basic colors, maybe a fill color feature and an eraser. The ability to save the drawing. It would be great if it had a publish feature to directly post it on twitter.
Is such tool available? And how can I embed it onto my website?
I work with html, css, javascript on my website.
I searched for such tools but could not find any.
Also I need to know how to embed the tool.
